# Sublime Text 2 and Python Packages

Tags: python, sublimetext2

I have started using Sublime Text 2 for my Python web application development. I cannot fathom out a way to create python packages (a folder with a `__init__.py`) file inside? You can create ordinary folders and then manually create the `__init__.py` file. This there no plugin to accomplish this.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a plugin, or how to write a plugin, or just complaining?  I'm not sure I see a question here.

Comment: I was asking if anyone know of a plugin. You can create new folders in the sidebar. Is there a plugin that allows you to create a package ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a Plugin to do that, if you are interested, you could use it as a base and improve it on your own way.

https://github.com/curaloucura/SublimePythonPackage